# Prevent a flex element from overflowing <body> by making its overflowing child have 100% of its width

Tags: css

I have a basic dashboard setup with a sidebar and I'm trying to have an element in the content area have an overflow scroll on the X axis.
However instead having an overflow scroll it makes its parent overflow.
I have tried with flex and grid-template-columns (1fr 5fr).
The behaviour I expect from the sidebar (not coded fully in my example) is `clamp(fixedminval, 1fr, fixedmaxval)`.
Here's the example :
https://codepen.io/fdsaazeazfazreazrazr/pen/ExJZRzg

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="container">
    <p>
      how can I make this element stop making its parent overflow and have its own X axis scrollbar // how can I make this element stop making its parent overflow and have its own X axis scrollbar // how can I make this element stop making its parent overflow and have its own X axis scrollbar
    </p>
  <div>
</div>

<style>
.content {
  display:flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 100vw;
}

.sidebar {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  background: grey;
}

.container {
  flex-grow: 5;
  flex-basis: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: salmon;
}

p {
  max-width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: scroll;
}
</style>
```

I tried many things particularly width and max-width but didn't find a way to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
  .content {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Prevent parent overflow */
  }

  .sidebar {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;
    background: grey;
  }

  .container {
    flex-grow: 5;
    flex-basis: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: salmon;
    overflow-x: auto; /* Enable horizontal scrolling */
    white-space: nowrap; /* Prevent line breaks */
  }

  .scrollable-content {
    width: max-content; /* Ensure the content doesn't wrap */
  }

  p {
    margin: 0;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks I modified your version on the codepen to make it so that only the P tag is scrollable...
https://codepen.io/fdsaazeazfazreazrazr/pen/ExJZRzg
Do you know why overflow-x auto is needed on the .container though ? I don't understand...

Comment: @ne3zy well i used chat-gpt so use that next time instead of asking on stackoverflow :)